# What is the most decent way to work with JavaScripts in Django projects?

Tags: javascript, django, packaging

Recently there have been a lot of changes in the frontend development, like Babel JavaScript compiler, and build systems like Browserify, Grunt, Gulp, Webpack, and others. Besides that, django-pipeline is also updated for the Django 1.10.

What is the most modern and promising way to deal with JavaScripts in a Django project in 2017?

Answer (score 2):

The question is opinion based as per me and to further your question, would you still like to use Django templating system or would you like to build api using Django Rest Framework and utilise the full power of Babel transpiler and ever improving JS frameworks to consume those apis?

Using build systems like Grunt/Gulp/Webpack can smoothen the management of static files which is a plus. But do ponder upon full fledged use of this tools in conjunction with some of the excellent JS frameworks that are available to provide a unique experience.

So what I am suggesting is go a step further use the tools you have mentioned and try out Angular/ReactJS/Aurelia or any other JS framework/library of your choice.

Comment: To be more concrete, I am about to use ReactJS with Ajax calls for some sections in a website, but most of the pages will use the usual Django templates. BTW, which of the build systems is the most popular nowadays?

Comment: If you are going to use ReactJS, I would suggest go with `webpack`.